# Can I somehow pick a specific number from a list?

Tags: python, list, numbers

I'm new at programming and i need help with my "work".
I need to print specific number from a list.
List = from 1 to 10 000  and i need to pick every single number that has "375" as a last three digits
For example: 375, 1375, 2375 etc.
My english isn't the best so I hope you undestood me right.
Thank you for your help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wl66V.png)
I know that that "random" shouldn't be there but i don't know what to do anymore

Comment: Learn about list comprehensions, and once you understand how to conditionally pick elements from a list the modulo operator will be useful for your specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a comprehension:

```
>>> [i+375 for i in range(0, 10000, 1000)]
[375, 1375, 2375, 3375, 4375, 5375, 6375, 7375, 8375, 9375]
```

A more generic way:

```
number = 375
start = 0
end = 10000
step = 10**len(str(number))
lst = [i+number for i in range(start, end, step)]
print(lst)

# Output
[375, 1375, 2375, 3375, 4375, 5375, 6375, 7375, 8375, 9375]
```